# DRF : 'DemoView' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a serializer without model.

**myproject/myapp/views.py :**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import DemoSerializer

class DemoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get(self, request):
        my_data = [{"name": "Harsha"}, {"name": "Harsha"}]
        results = DemoSerializer(my_data, many=True).data
        return Response(results)
```

**myproject/myapp/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('demo', views.DemoView, basename='Demo')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**myproject/myapp/serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class DemoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
```

When I goto URL: `http://localhost:8000/demo/`, it is giving me following **error**:

***DemoView should either include a queryset attribute, or override the get_queryset() method.***

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Why are you using `ModelViewSet` if you don't have model ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from .models import Demo

class DemoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Demo.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        my_data = [{"name": "Harsha"}, {"name": "Harsha"}]
        results = DemoSerializer(my_data, many=True).data
        return Response(results)
```

If you don't want to create a model then you should extend `viewsets.ViewSet`.

```
class DemoView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def get(self, request):
        my_data = [{"name": "Harsha"}, {"name": "Harsha"}]
        results = DemoSerializer(my_data, many=True).data
        return Response(results)
```

Comment: see 1st line of question: `I want to create a serializer without model.` Still I have to create model?

Comment: Basically, how can I override the get_queryset() method without model?

Comment: `(viewsets.ViewSet)` is not working. `The current path, demo/, didn’t match any of these.` Not even URL is exist in this case

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to customize `list` method if you inherit from the `ModelViewSet`.

```
class DemoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Demo.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        my_data = [{"name": "Harsha"}, {"name": "Harsha"}]
        results = DemoSerializer(my_data, many=True).data
        return Response(results)
```